# C++ class/struct conversion to void* pointer and reverse

Tags: c++11, casting

I have a class:

```
class A
{
public:
   A (A& in) {} // How to write a constructor from void* ?
   int a;
   int b;
   const void* data() const { return static_cast<const void *>(this); }
};
```

I need to pass the class data thru a connection, which takes a `void*` buffer and "returns" also `void*`. An instance and some function:

```
  A a;
  void send(void* x);
  void receive(void* x);
```

- How can I type cast the `a` to send it as a parameter to `foo()`? The following code is not valid:

  foo(static_cast<A&>(a));
- How can I then, create a new object from a `void* x` pointer? What constructor and type cast to implement?

  void* pA;
  pA = ...
  A a_copy {pA};
- What would be the difference, if I have a struct not a class? I assume POD class here.

I would like not to use c-style casts, but rather C++ constructs.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I type cast the a to send it as a parameter to `foo()`? The following code is not valid:
>
> ```
> foo(static_cast<A&>(a));
> ```

I assume you mean `send()` instead of `foo()`? If so, your code is not valid because you are casting it to a reference to `A`, when `send()` expects a pointer to `void`. So:

```
send(static_cast<void *>(&a));
```

Or, since you already have a member function that does the casting for you:

```
send(a.data());
```

> How can I then, create a new object from a `void* x` pointer? What constructor and type cast to implement?

If you really want to do that, then again your constructor should take a pointer to `void` as argument, not a reference to another `A`:

```
class A
{
public:
   A(void* in) {...}
   ...
};
```

You could then use [`std::memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy all data into the class

```
A(void *in) {
    std::memcpy(this, in, sizeof *this);
};
```

Of course, this should only be done if `A` is a POD type.

> What would be the difference, if I have a `struct` not a `class`? I assume POD class here.

Nothing. A `struct` and a `class` are the same, the exception is just that `struct` defaults to making members `public`, and a class defaults to `private`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

`A(void *in) {  std::memcpy(this, in, sizeof *this);  };`

Is there a way to have the new class constructed from the `void*` pointer without using of `std::memcopy()` ?

Comment: Apart from using `std::memmove()` instead of `std::memcpy()`, no. The reason you can only use this is because it is the only valid way to [create an object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_creation) without resorting to [`std::reinterpret_cast<>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), and the latter is problematic as well. Consider that the pointer you get might not meet the alignment restrictions of `class A`.